# Xtext: Calling the Generator from a Context Menu

Tags: xtext

Following

https://christiandietrich.wordpress.com/2011/10/15/xtext-calling-the-generator-from-a-context-menu/

and using `EclipseResourceFileSystemAccess2` instead of `EclipseResourceFileSystemAccess` when the line

```
final EclipseResourceFileSystemAccess2 fsa = fileAccessProvider.get();
```

give an exception. The only information I have is

```
// Compiled from InvocationTargetException.java (version 1.8 : 52.0, super bit)
public class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException extends java.lang.ReflectiveOperationException {
```

I don't know how to get the stack trace in Eclipse.

does the code in the blog still function in the most recent release of Xtext?

**Update 1**

Snippets from plugin.xml

Handler:

```
<extension
   point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
  <handler
      class="tuks.mcrl2.dsl.ui.handlers.Mcrl22Lps"
      commandId="tuks.mcrl2.dsl.ui.commands.mcrl2lps">
  </handler>
 </extension>
```

Commands:

```
<extension
   point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
 <command
      categoryId="tuks.mcrl2.dsl.ui.category.processalgebra"
      defaultHandler="tuks.mcrl2.dsl.ui.handlers.Mcrl22Lps"
      description="Conver a mclr2 file to lps"
      id="tuks.mcrl2.dsl.ui.commands.mcrl2lps"
      name="mcrl22lps">
 </command>
 <category
      id="tuks.mcrl2.dsl.ui.category.processalgebra"
      name="Process Algebra">
 </category>
</extension>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it basically works, if you do the update from EclipseResourceFileSystemAccess and Stuff and (maybe) IGenerator.
I assume in your case you dont set the Accesses ProgressMonitor and other props.

```java
package org.xtext.example.mydsl.ui.handler;

import org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionEvent;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException;
import org.eclipse.core.commands.IHandler;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IFolder;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.NullProgressMonitor;
import org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.Resource;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.ResourceSet;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ISelection;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.IStructuredSelection;
import org.eclipse.ui.handlers.HandlerUtil;
import org.eclipse.xtext.builder.EclipseResourceFileSystemAccess2;
import org.eclipse.xtext.generator.GeneratorContext;
import org.eclipse.xtext.generator.IGenerator2;
import org.eclipse.xtext.resource.IResourceDescriptions;
import org.eclipse.xtext.ui.resource.IResourceSetProvider;

import com.google.inject.Inject;
import com.google.inject.Provider;

public class GenerationHandler extends AbstractHandler implements IHandler {

    @Inject
    private IGenerator2 generator;

    @Inject
    private Provider<EclipseResourceFileSystemAccess2> fileAccessProvider;

    @Inject
    IResourceDescriptions resourceDescriptions;

    @Inject
    IResourceSetProvider resourceSetProvider;

    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {

        ISelection selection = HandlerUtil.getCurrentSelection(event);
        if (selection instanceof IStructuredSelection) {
            IStructuredSelection structuredSelection = (IStructuredSelection) selection;
            Object firstElement = structuredSelection.getFirstElement();
            if (firstElement instanceof IFile) {
                IFile file = (IFile) firstElement;
                IProject project = file.getProject();
                IFolder srcGenFolder = project.getFolder("src-gen");
                if (!srcGenFolder.exists()) {
                    try {
                        srcGenFolder.create(true, true,
                                new NullProgressMonitor());
                    } catch (CoreException e) {
                        return null;
                    }
                }

                final EclipseResourceFileSystemAccess2 fsa = fileAccessProvider.get();
                fsa.setProject(project);
                fsa.setOutputPath("src-gen");
                fsa.setMonitor(new NullProgressMonitor()); 
                URI uri = URI.createPlatformResourceURI(file.getFullPath().toString(), true);
                ResourceSet rs = resourceSetProvider.get(project);
                Resource r = rs.getResource(uri, true);
                generator.doGenerate(r, fsa, new GeneratorContext());

            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

and make sure you register the handler properly.
the

```java
class="org.xtext.example.mydsl.ui.MyDslExecutableExtensionFactory:org.xtext.example.mydsl.ui.handler.GenerationHandler"
```

is crucial, especially that it consists of 2 parts, the `ExtensionFactory` followed by a `:` followed by the actual class name

Comment: The variable `fileAccessProvider` is null in my implementation.

Comment: how does you registration of handler in plugin.xml look like?

Comment: You need to write xxx.YourdslExecutsbleExtensionFactory:xxx.YourHandler do get guice working

Comment: The handle is now the class specified by `class="tuks.mcrl2.dsl.ui.MclrDslExecutableExtensionFactory:tuks.mcrl2.dsl.ui.handler.Mcrl2Lps"` but still get that `fileAccessProvider` is still `null`

Comment: can you please share a complete reproducing example as a git repo

Comment: it looks like you missed some places e.g.  defaultHandler="tuks.mcrl2.dsl.ui.MclrDslExecutableExtensionFactory:tuks.mcrl2.dsl.ui.handler.Mcrl2Lps"