# Cannot generate output file using in xtext using IFileSystemAccess2

Tags: xtext

Using the method in

https://christiandietrich.wordpress.com/2011/10/15/xtext-calling-the-generator-from-a-context-menu/

to call a function for a model to text transformation. The classes used to generate the text file is not the same as in the example:

```
class TransformMcrl2{

   def doGenerate(Resource input, IFileSystemAccess2 fsa, IGeneratorContext context) {
       fsa.generateFile("testfile.txt" , "Content")
   }

}
```

and the code segment used to call `doGenerate`

```
// load the Xtext model to an XtextResourceSet
XtextResourceSet resourceSet = aresourceSetProvider.get();
// get the resource and resolve all references
Resource resource = resourceSet.getResource(uri, true);
EcoreUtil.resolveAll(resource);
IResource documentResource = xtextDocument.getAdapter(IResource.class);
IProject project = documentResource.getProject();

final EclipseResourceFileSystemAccess2 fsa = fileAccessProvider.get();
IFolder srcGenFolder = project.getFolder("lps-gen");
if (!srcGenFolder.exists()) {
    try {
        srcGenFolder.create(true, true, new NullProgressMonitor());
    } catch (CoreException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
fsa.setProject(project);
String tmpFileName = srcGenFolder.getFullPath().toString();
fsa.setOutputPath(tmpFileName);

TransformMcrl2 generator = new TransformMcrl2();
generator.doGenerate(resource, fsa, new GeneratorContext());
```

the method doGenerate give an exception `InvocationTargetException` and itws cause indicate the error is a NullPointerException.

Do I need to inherit from IGenerator?

Also `org.eclipse.xtext.builder.participant` was not disabled as more than one model to text conversation will be necessary.

Comment: this the same question as already answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41665691/xtext-calling-the-generator-from-a-context-menu/41666069#41666069 e.g. the access should need a progress monitor and a different output path

Comment: No related, I continued to the next step, The output folder under the project is `lps-gen` and the file name is for now fixed in `doGenerate`

Comment: yes but the code is different and that might cause your problem

Comment: added `fsa.setMonitor(new NullProgressMonitor())` the exceptions are gone, but the file is not created.

Comment: sure you did the sourcefolder thing right= should be setOutputPath("lps-gen")

Comment: works now :-) in the code of the question used  `fsa.setOutputPath(srcGenFolder.getName());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure

1. you create stuff like generator via guice
2. set the Progress Monitor of the File System Access
3. set the output path correct `fsa.setOutputPath("xxx")`